# SQL Server - Are permissions on tables required?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

My question again to be more specific:
How can I modify data through a view and don't have to grant SELECT-Permissions on the table?

I am designing and developing a new database at the company i am working for.
The business rules say, that users are allowed to access specific rows in tables only.
So I use views to check the permissions of the user and return only those records, the user has access to.

So far so god.
But, I have to check the permissions also on INSERT and UPDATE and DELETE with INSTEAD-of-Triggers. Because the rows a User can SELECT may not be those, he can modify.

My problem is:
When I have an view and grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE Permissions, it doesn't work. When I insert into this view, SQL Server wants INSERT-Permission at the base table. That wouldn't be a problem. But when I update or delete rows through the view, SQL Server wants SELECT and UPDATE/DELETE permissions granted on the base table. 
I don't want to give SELECT-rights on the table.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Using triggers for security is a worse idea than invading Russia in the winter.  I'd go back to the drawing board.

Comment: thanks. Is this the common practice to update data through a view? When I have to use EXECUTE AS, I have to keep the name of the login in secret. Because someone knows the LOGIN-Name that has permissions at table level, he could login with his own account in SQL Server and use EXECUTE AS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking at:

1/ Restrict VIEW rows by adding in its definition a condition like this:

```
WHERE UserName = SUSER_SNAME()
or
WHERE UserName = CURRENT_USER()
```

or

2/ Using [INSTEAD OF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521.aspx) triggers on the involved view.

*P.S. Indeed, CREATE VIEW WITH EXECUTE is not allowed. Thank you for your messages.*

Comment: in my case every user has his own LOGIN on SQL-Server. Thanks, I'll try this solution.

Comment: You can work on role so. You can give the public role no right, add a user as ddl_reader and execute your view as that user. Are you talking about sql user or windows users? If it's windows use active directory group for your user and add it. Ah yes take care with this logic of view, you can have problem with inter database connection. I did it with no problem but it can happen. You have info about that on this website.

Comment: EXECUTE AS is not allowed for views. It is also not allowed for FUNCTIONS which return a table. So, the only use of EXECUTE AS seems to work with Stored Procedures. I don't understand that security concept.